# How to prepare for undergraduate research of which I have no background in?

Tags: research-process, internship

I recently applied and got accepted to a very large research lab in the U.S. Although the catch is that I did not get put into my major ( Biology ) and instead was placed into computer science ( simulations/super computing).

I reason this is because I had several computer science classes in the past, but I eventually changed majors to biology due to not flourishing with high level maths or coding.

I assume that to prepare for any research, one must read the supervisor's papers and self study. Although the issue is I feel I am totally outmatched for this position, due to my struggles in computer science before. Is there a good strategy for approaching this upcoming internship or should I resign instead?

Comment: I'm confused -- is the internship even a biology-oriented internship? Or did you explicitly apply for a computer science internship?

Comment: The internship was for all types of undergraduate STEM based science, as it is a very large lab that hosts it. I think the issue was I applied for biology research experience, but the closest host lab I could attend also had the smallest biology department.

Comment: @tonysdg if you turn that into an answer, I'll upvote it, because it makes the points "talk to them" and "biology is an important part of computational biology". I wouldn't say programming the simulation is "easy" but that it's fruitless if you haven't thought it through from the biology side. You could generalize that to: domain knowledge is an important part of most programming tasks because without it you're going to program the wrong thing. One of the  goals of the internship might be to practice working with/as the domain expert.

Comment: @tonysdg          Do you have any suggestions on how to word such a communication? I was thinking along the lines of:  "Hello Dr.  [Name], I was chosen to be a prospective undergraduate research assistant for the spring semester. However, I have to be honest with you in that I feel unprepared for the position as my computer science skills were always weaker than my Biology skills,as it is my current major. Do you have any advice for how I can be of most use to you for the spring semester, as in what I should be attempt to be more than proficient on before my arrival?   Regards Rosiv"

Comment: @Sumyrda: Done. Thanks for doing a much better job than I did at explaining why domain experts matter :)

Comment: @RoSiv: Can you move your comment to my answer below?

Answer (score 3):

My advice is to discuss this matter directly with whoever your supervisor will be -- tell them about your past experience, your concerns, and ask for their advice. They may be able to have you shifted -- or they may tell you that they were explicitly looking for your biology background.

As to why they would be explicitly looking for your biology backgrounds -- computer scientists frequently collaborate with other scientists when working on large-scale simulations. The reason for this is that there's two sides to the simulation -- the actual code required to run it, and the domain knowledge required to design the code in the first place. As @Sumyrda pointed out, this may be one of the goals of the internship (to give you experience in working with/as the domain expert).